# Is state management only a frontend concern?

Tags: backend, state-management

I'm currently learning Redux and I see a great benefit to having one source of truth for state. I was wondering if the backend could benefit from state management also, but I see nothing online about it, so I assume not. Although I found [this](https://github.com/luisvinicius167/godux) which seems like it is actually aiming to bring redux state management concepts to the backend..but I may be misinterpreting it.

Does the backend typically not maintain enough state in memory to be worth having state management - and we will not likely see Redux-like patterns on the backend?

Comment: 5.5 years later, what do you think about the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

State management is a fundamental thing in software, we need always to keep track of our data in backend or frontend.

So to be more direct, it's **not** only a frontend concern, please check out this [example of using redux](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/docs/usage/ServerRendering.md) on the server

That being said, state management it's not always needed ( think about stateless apps! )

With apps like chat applications with Socket.io ( I'm just giving you some ideas ), you might need redux ( or other libs if there any ) to keep track of the history of the chat, so that when your users reload their tab they can poll the server - you have also to manage the dabase sync with your state.

Comment: Thanks. In the [example of using redux on the server](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/recipes/ServerRendering.md) it says "Redux's only job on the server side is to provide the initial state of our app". I would call it state initialisation as opposed to management. It seems like backend state management is covered by a database. I don't see backend tools for state management resembling frontend state management, that are currently popular. This is just me explaining what it seems like from my research as opposed to stating how it is.

Answer (score 1):

If you are thinking in redux in express, probably is not best idea for some reasons:
1. Your app should be stateless
2. Your source of truth is the database.

If you would want implement a state managment for don't stress our db or for caching/speed, you could implement a redis (or similar) as state managment.